# How to display a message before login?

Tags: linux, debian

I need to display a message **before** any login on a Linux box, either locally and for remote login via SSH.

How can I achieve this?

#### Edit:

Thanks for your answers. I had to pick one accepted answer, but both are correct and complement each other.

"issue" and "Banner" are the two concepts I need to use to provide a message for every user before they log into the system.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For local login (or telnet) you need to modify:

```
/etc/motd
```

For display a message **before** login you edit instead

```
/etc/issue
```

see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-login-message/

Comment: +1 (motd being the abbreviation of "message of the day").

Comment: is the motd displayed before the user is asked for a password ?

Comment: The contents of /etc/motd are displayed by login(1) after a successful login but just before it executes the login shell.

Answer (score 14):

For SSH, you need to change the `Banner` config option in `sshd_config`:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/change-openssh-sshd-server-login-banner.html

Comment: sure, but that will only display a message after a login name was given through ssh-connection. Any ideas displaying a banner / message before 'login: ' ?

Comment: It does "display a banner / message before 'login: '". This is the most direct answer. Banner does not have a default value.